# Is my proof of $f(A_1\cap A_2)\subset f(A_1)\cap f(A_2)$ correct?

Tags: functions, solution-verification

My attempt:Let $x\in A_1\cap A_2$(1)

This implies that $f(x)\in f(A_1\cap A_2)$(2)

Now (1) implies that $x\in A_1$ and $x\in A_2$

This implies $f(x)\in f(A_1)$ and $f(x)\in f(A_2)$(3)

By (2) and (3) we have,

$f(A_1\cap A_2)\subset f(A_1)\cap f(A_2)$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually you can write  $x \in A_1 \cap A_2$ implies that $x \in A_1$ and $x \in A_2$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to start with an element in the first set and show it must be in the second.  In other words, you can't start with $x\in A_1\cap A_2$,  you need to start with some generic element $y\in f( A_1\cap A_2)$

By definition of being in the image of a set under a function, that means there exists an $x\in A_1\cap A_2$ such that $f(x)=y$.

From there you can proceed to show that $y$ is in the RHS

Comment: Thank you so much!